# TypeError: Object of type TextIOWrapper is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py, python-3.7

If the code was to work properly then whenever someone types something in the chat they get 5 experience and that information gets put into a `.json` file, but instead what happens is whenever someone types something into the chat it gives me this error.

```
on_message users = json.dumps(f) 
TypeError: Object of type TextIOWrapper is not JSON serializable
```

Here is the code that I am using:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
import json
from json import dumps, loads, JSONEncoder, JSONDecoder
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='^')
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\quiny\Desktop\sauce')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("Ready when you are xd")
    print ("I am running on " + client.user.name)
    print ("With the ID: " + client.user.id)

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f: 
        users = json.dumps(f)

    await update_data(users, member)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.loads("users, f")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.dumps(f)

    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
    await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.loads("users, f")

async def update_data(users, user):
    if not user.id in users:
        users[user.id] = {}
        users[user.id]['experience'] = 0
        users[user.id]['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
    users[user.id]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel):
    experience = users[user.id]['experience']
    lvl_start = users[user.id]['level']
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))

    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await client.send_message(channel, '{} has achieved a slightly higher 
level of {}, yay'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
        users[user.id]['level'] = lvl_end
```

Comment: FWIW: I got that very error because I accidentally swapped the arguments to `json.dump()`, e.g. I used `json.dump(fp, obj)` instead of the proper `json.dump(obj, fp)`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have your [`loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) and [`dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) backwards, and you should be using [`load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) and [`dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) instead (the `s` suffix means those functions work on strings.).  `load` from a file, `dump` to a file

```
users = {}

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # No need to load the dictionary, our copy is the most correct
    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
    await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)
    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("Ready when you are xd")
    print ("I am running on " + client.user.name)
    print ("With the ID: " + client.user.id)
    # Load the json just once, when the bot starts
    global users
    with open('users.json') as f:
        try:
            users = json.load(f)
        except:
            users = {}
```

Answer (score 40):

I had this error and I used the `json.dump` the wrong way around:

### Correct way:

```py
with open("Jello.json", "w") as json_file:
    json.dump(object_to_be_saved, json_file)
```

### Wrong way:

I did it the other way around `json.dump(json_file, object_to_be_saved)`... Thanks Python.